# LetterCountI CoderByte. Raises Exception with working code

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash, version

Learning programming so sorry for a beginner question! Here I have a code that works in my sublime text editor but raises an exception on Coderbyte, which from what I know uses Ruby 1.8.7. I suspect it might have to do with the different versions of Ruby. Would be helpful to understand what is going wrong. Thanks for replying!

Exception raised is:

```
(eval):9: undefined method `keys' for []:Array (NoMethodError)  from (eval):4:in `each' from (eval):4:in `LetterCountI' from (eval):23

def LetterCountI(str)

  str = str.split
  repeating_letters = []
  str.each do |word| 
    word = word.split("")
    letters = Hash.new(0)
    word.each { |letter| letters[letter] += 1 }
    selected_letters = letters.select { |key, value| value > 1 }
    repeating_letters << selected_letters.keys.length
  end
  if (repeating_letters.select {|l| l >= 1}).empty?
    return -1
  else
    max = repeating_letters.max
    p repeating_letters
    return str[repeating_letters.index(max)]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's the versions. In Ruby 1.8.7 `hash.select` [returns an Array](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Hash.html#method-i-select),  which has no `keys` method. In later versions `select` returns a Hash.